# Is there a function to get all gardens from google maps?

Tags: c#

I'm setting up an application for people to help them find the park they want - I would like to get all the locations marked as 'garden', 'park' or other related terms from google map to my database - Is there such an API?

Comment: Are you using the Places (`https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search`) API?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) of Google Maps. Pick the method that suits your use case. Lets say you would to use the `Nearby Search` method, you could supply what [place types](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types) of fields you wish Maps to return to you. To get all nearby parks for example, you could include *park* as place type. Note that you can combine multiple field types and you can even supply multiple, different, types to perform a more complex search, see the [place types](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types) page for more information.

> I need to get all the gardens from google map to my dataBase in sql

Is this a requirement? Why not request the data from Maps when the user actually requires the data instead of preemptively crawling all of Google Maps into your SQL, which IMO would be overkill. Useless your application solely functions offline I wouldn't recommend doing this.

If you need any helping implementing this into your application feel free to update your main post with the code you have so far and I (or someone else) will help you out for sure!